# How to sync update value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular so here goes. I have an upload avatar and a thumbnail to show the image of the uploaded avatar. My problem is how to update the thumbnail of the newly uploaded avatar. Coz as of right now I would have to refresh the page first before I can see the changes.

Here's some code in my controller:

```
//get avatar
$scope.userAvatar = function() {
    Api.getAvatar($scope.security.currentUser.email)
    .then(function(result) {
        //success
        $scope.avatarImage = result.config.url;
    }, function(result) {
        //errors
        console.log(result);
    });
}

//validate avatar then upload avatar
$scope.validateAvatar = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    if(files.length > 0) 
    {
        $scope.filesize = files[0].size;
        $scope.filemaxsize = 25 * 1024;
        $scope.$apply();

    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("avatarImage", files[0]);
        $scope.uploadAvatar = function() {
            Api.uploadAvatar($scope.security.currentUser.email, fd)
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result.data);
                //$scope.avatarImage = result.config.url; ////doesn't update the $scope.avatarImage
                //$scope.userAvatar(); //doesn't update the $scope.avatarImage
                Api.getAvatar($scope.security.currentUser.email)
                .then(function(result) {
                    //success
                    console.log('uploaded Image');
                    $scope.avatarImage = result.config.url;
                });
            }, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
        };  
    }
};
```

and on my partials

```
<div id="show-avatar" class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-3">
    <img id="avatarbox" ng-src="{{avatarImage}}" >
</div>
```

On my controller code above I validate the chosen image first if its not more than 25kb I show the upload button. I included the code on how I upload my avatar maybe it may help on my problem.

Comment: Return the path or name of image from the server and update the source of the image in the callback.

Comment: hmm, the return of the uploadAvatar is just a success message. And for the callback I included the $scope.userAvatar(); after the success callback in my uploadAvatar. But it didn't work. :(

Comment: Is te name of the image contained anywhere in the `result.data`?

Comment: @tymeJV, nope. The response are these: Object {status: "Uploaded", message: "Avatar for player user@domain.com saved."}. I'm been reading about $broadcast, $on, $emit, $rootScope but aren't helpful enough for a newbie :(

Comment: Once it gets uploaded, I see you set the source to `result.config.url` from the `getAvatar` function. Why dont you run this in the callback?

Comment: I've tried those also, see my update question. I've updated the controller code, added the two callbacks. Is that what you mean? Sorry.

Comment: Yeah, on the right track, you have to run the entire API call again `Api.getAvatar($scope.security.currentUser.email)
    .then(function(result) {` in the callback, then set the `result.config.url` inside that

Comment: sorry for the late response, it was past after midnight. Had to go home. But I tried today what you suggested, I also added a console.log just to be sure it gets through to the success callback and it does but it still didn't work. :(. See my updated question

Comment: Hmm, what is the log result of `result.config.url` in the new addition to the callback?

Comment: hi, config.url: http://localhost:8080/api-server/1.0/player/user@domain.com/avatar. This is the same url I passed on getting the avatarImage in $scope.userAvatar().

Comment: Well that's good...and the controller should be updating...can you try hard-coding this path in the callback to see if it sets it? Trying to narrow down the list of possibilities

Comment: hmm, this is weird. I tried changing the url just to make sure the scope really gets updated and it does. The problem is the thumbnail image doesn't. Could it be cached? Is there a way to load just the image element?

Comment: Well, I don't think caching should be the issue (wouldn't throw it out just yet), but I know Angular does nothing when the ng-src goes blank, but you say it's updating, weird...I'm at a bit of a loss for now, going to look it over for a bit.

Comment: @tymeJV, finally solved it. Look at the answer below. Thanks a lot for the aid. Really appreciate it men.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i solved my own problem with the below code.

```
$scope.validateAvatar = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    if(files.length > 0) 
    {
        $scope.filesize = files[0].size;
        $scope.filemaxsize = 25 * 1024;
        $scope.avatarImage = '';            
        //Take the first selected file
        fd.append("avatarImage", files[0]);
        $scope.uploadAvatar = function() {
            Api.uploadAvatar($scope.security.currentUser.email, fd)
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.userAvatar();
            }, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            })
        };  
        $scope.$apply();
    }
};
```

I reset the $scope.avatarImage then assign it again using the $scope.userAvatar();.